# Want to add discounted price field to Cross sell tab in magento

Tags: magento, discount

I want to implement following requirement in magento admin panel-

When I add 'A' product to shopping cart then system suggest me 'B','C'.. products with discount price which I already configured through admin panel.i.e want to make a provision to select products and add discounted price..like cross sell tab.

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 0):

i think i want the same... use the magento crosssell function to display a particular product(s) at the checkout of another unique product in the normal way. the extra feature required is to hard code a promotional price or % discount into the crosssell item. if a sku 123456 is in the product view or category it has a retail price but if show in crosssell it is shown with a promotional discounted price that is controlled at product level. so maybe this feature is part of the product setup. maybe a new field called crosssell price ?

i have asked aheadworks for clarification on the function of their 'checkout promo' extension.
the ahead works extension seems to be a banner but i'll see what they say.

Answer (score 0):

Is this to use the magento crosssell function to display a particular product(s) at the checkout of another unique product in the normal way? The extra feature required is to hard code a promotional price or % discount into the crosssell item. If a sku 123456 is in the product view or category it has a retail price but if show in crosssell it is shown with a promotional discounted price that is controlled at product level. So maybe this feature is part of the product setup, maybe it's a new field called crosssell price ?

I have asked aheadworks for clarification on the function of their 'checkout promo' extension.
The ahead works, extension seems to be a banner but I'll see what they say.